# How to identify which thread am I at?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two two threads running and performing the same method. How can I distinguish which one of them is the one I am currently at?

Example:
I have method `GetTable()` will return new DataTable dt have data.

```
public void GetTable()
{
    browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome, 0);
    browser.GoToUrl(link);

    DataTable dt;
    if(thread == 1)
        ExcelSave(dt, "sheet1");

    else if(thread == 2)
        ExcelSave(dt, "sheet2");
}
```

I want to detect: if a first thread must save to `sheet1` in excel file, second thread keeps to `sheet2` in excel file.

Question 2:

First, it will create two `browser`, and `browser.GoToUrl(link)` only working(twice) in a second thread.

This mean: `Thread 1` and `Thread 2` was create two process Chrome browser. But when to go to rows `browser.GoToUrl(link)` only working in `Thread 2`. `Thread 2` execute code `browser.GoToUrl(link)` twice.

My code like:

```
    Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetTable));
    Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetTable));

    tid1.Start();
    tid2.Start();
```

I was using:

`Parallel.Invoke(() => GetTable(), () => GetTable());`

Also: I don't know if using Thread run parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azodious's and Hari's suggestion will work but I think a better design approach, if possible to change, will be that at the code that executes the 2 threads to pass the sheet to write to as a parameter.

Comment: Something like this: `public void GetTable(string sheetToStore)
{
    browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome, 0);
    browser.GoToUrl(link);

    DataTable dt;
        ExcelSave(dt, sheetToStore);
}`

    Also, in the code that you are calling this function, with the threads, if possible I'd recomment to use `Tasks` instead. It is nicer and cleaner to use

Comment: I updated my question(at question 2). Can you see more?

Comment: I don't really understand your second question

Comment: My purpose is: I create two Thread, each thread will get a DataTable. I will compare two DataTable from two Thread. But I have problem when I navigation to link.  At rows: `browser = new Lapsoft_OneDriver(Browsers.Chrome, 0);` will create new process chrome. So, I have two thread, `Thread 1` and `Thread 2` created two processes. After, each thread must be navigation to link. But my problem is: `Thread 1` not run to line: `browser.GoToUrl(link);`, at this time, `Thread 2` run twice this line.

Comment: Please first edit the code according to the suggestions and test it. I don't think that that line happens twice in the second thread. Also how does the data from the GoToUrl gets into the DataTable? Is that function also async? If so you should wait for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115812/discussion-between-vn-lc-and-gilad-green).

Answer (score 2):

You could name the [`Thread.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it for identification.

```
    if(Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Thread1")
    {
        // logic
    }
    else
    {
        // else logic
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a problem in an answer. Can you see: `First, it will create two browsers, and browser.GoToUrl(link) only working(twice) in a second thread.`. This mean: `Thread 1` and `Thread 2` was create two process Chrome browser. But when to go to rows `browser.GoToUrl(link)` only working in `Thread 2`. `Thread 2` execute `GoToUrl` twice.

Comment: Where are  the threads created? please mind calling creating a `browser` or calling `GoToUrl` will not create threads. It is hard to suggest something unless we see your code.

Comment: I created threads in `Main` and two threads call to method `GetTable()`. In `GetTable()` i tried to build new process browser and navigation to link. But seem working in `thread 2`.

Comment: Can you include thread creation code and calling `GetTable`  code?

Comment: I'm updated my code. I usually using `Parallel.Invoke(() => GetTable(), () => GetTable());`. But in case I using Thread to detect `Thread.Name`.

Comment: You will get the thread name which invoked, check this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WES2C3)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to detect, if a first thread must save to sheet1 in excel file, second thread keeps to sheet2 in excel file.

Assign names to thread when creating them. and check that name in your `GetTable` method.

> And I don't know if using Thread run parallel.

On multi-core, yes.

Comment: Can you see my question was updated? I have problem when using Thread.